# TSQL XML Field - How to update tag with a condition of another tag at the same level

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery

With this structure

```
<users>
  <user>
    <fname>Josef</fname>
    <lname>Brown</lname>
    <email_>jo0@adventure-works.com</email_>
    <gender>Male</gender>
  </user>
  <user>
    <fname>Katie</fname>
    <lname>McAskill-White</lname>
    <email_>katie0@adventure-works.com</email_>
  </user>
</users>


xml.modify('replace value of (/users/user/fname/text()) with "Kat"')
```

I need to add a where / condition to only update fname text, when the text of email is equal lets say katie0@adventure-works.com.

All of the examples I can find only work when the condition is on the path, but not at the same level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following.

If needed, you can use SQL Server variables as parameters for the XQuery.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<users>
  <user>
    <fname>Josef</fname>
    <lname>Brown</lname>
    <email_>jo0@adventure-works.com</email_>
    <gender>Male</gender>
  </user>
  <user>
    <fname>Katie</fname>
    <lname>McAskill-White</lname>
    <email_>katie0@adventure-works.com</email_>
  </user>
</users>';

DECLARE @email VARCHAR(128) = 'katie0@adventure-works.com';

-- SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/users/user[email_="katie0@adventure-works.com"]/fname/text())[1] with "Kat"');
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/users/user[email_=sql:variable("@email")]/fname/text())[1] with "Kat"');

-- test
SELECT @xml;
```

**Output**

```
<users>
  <user>
    <fname>Josef</fname>
    <lname>Brown</lname>
    <email_>jo0@adventure-works.com</email_>
    <gender>Male</gender>
  </user>
  <user>
    <fname>Kat</fname>
    <lname>McAskill-White</lname>
    <email_>katie0@adventure-works.com</email_>
  </user>
</users>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This should work and will try it tonight.

Comment: The answer is a **minimal reproducible example**. You copy it to SSMS, run it as-is, and it is working.